# Energy conversion efficiency of Q-switched laser?

Tags: laser

This is kind of an elementary question, but since i cannot find a reliable source on this i wanted to ask what is the formula for energy conversion efficiency? I know efficiency is calculated as useful energy out/energy in, but i've been reading some papers on Q-switching, and some people have used Energy(pump)/Energy(Q-switch) which is the same as Energy(in)/Energy(out). Could anyone please clarify this? If it isn't as i said, can the energy conversion efficiency be more than 1? Also, i was wondering what is the max efficiency that Q-switched (Nd:YAG) lasers get? I ended up getting around 58%

Comment: There are a lot of ways to Q-switch, both passive and active.  I doubt there's any way to get an accurate calculation from a model, so measure wall-plug power draw and use an optical meter designed to report energy in short pulses to determine the output.